# Django: How do I know if a field value is required?

Tags: django, forms, sqlite

In the `category` model, for testing reasons, I set the field attribute for `name` to `unique=False`, and then called `./manage.py syncdb`.
Then I submit a form where the field for this attribute is empty (note I'm setting `required=False`). Because this form has already been submitted once without any value for the field `name`, as well, a `category` with no `name` is already in the database (I see it in `admin`) and I get the error

> column name is not unique

Is it a SQLite requirement that column names have to be unique? And does that imply that every required field *must* have a value on submit (or so at least default values)?

**EDIT**

Model:

> class Category(models.Model):
>
> ```
>  name  = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=False)
>  views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
>  likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
>
>  def __unicode__(self):
>      return self.name
> ```

ModelForm:

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name  = forms.CharField(max_length=128,
                            help_text="Enter category name.",
                            required=False)
    case_sensitive = forms.BooleanField(help_text="Case sensitive?", required=False)
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

    class Meta:
        # Associate ModelForm and a model.
        model = Category
```

Comment: Can you show us your model code? Are you using [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form)? Are you using the [`required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#required) attribute in your field?

Comment: added the code, I'm setting `required=False` explicitly.

Comment: Can you please post the entire stack trace?  The error type would be most helpful.  Is it an IntegrityError?

Answer (score 0):

`syncdb` won't work here because you have already created tables in database and  altered model fields which( altered fields) can't be synced by `syncdb`( Thats why field name is unique error is occurring). From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#syncdb):

> syncdb will only create tables for models which have not yet been
>   installed. It will never issue ALTER TABLE statements to match changes
>   made to a model class after installation. Changes to model classes and
>   database schemas often involve some form of ambiguity and, in those
>   cases, Django would have to guess at the correct changes to make.
>   There is a risk that critical data would be lost in the process.
>
> If you have made changes to a model and wish to alter the database
>   tables to match, use the sql command to display the new SQL structure
>   and compare that to your existing table schema to work out the
>   changes.

Here you have to use `migration`. You can use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) to migrate database